# How do you earn the Winter Bash 2018 clean-up duty hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018, secret-hat

I ran across this post:

*[Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list/319840#319840)*

On MSE (for all the secret hats), and I realized that the answer doesn't contain the explanation of Clean-Up duty hat. I am just wondering how you get it?

On the chat of Winter Bash, they gave me an idea to re-tag some old questions and some new ones, but that did not work. They also told me to try edit 5 questions that I up-voted on, but that didn't work either, so that's why I am asking.

<del>(Note: I don't ask why for the Waffle hat, because I got it already, even though I still don't know how I did it :D)</del>

Waffle hat is discovered, see above link.

Comment: It may also have to do with working the review queues.

Comment: Cleanup duty is a secret hat. Anyone who finds out what triggers it would probably have posted it there, so it seems nobody knows for sure what it is. Most people figure out how to get a hat through trial and error.

Comment: Amm.. i know that... that's why i am asking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Hope my answer would help you, recently I got the clean-up hat, before getting this hat, my recent activities were</strike>

**EDIT - 2** : supporting review queue (I almost cleared 25-30 Q/A) this got me the **Peacekeeper Hat**, I checked it after @U9-Forward reminded me of that.

So, flagging duplicate/off-topic questions (All this done on SO main), is the activity **Also not worked out for the Hat**.

Than editing the tags was also one of my activities that I forgot to mention previously thanks to @WELZ for correcting me, It should be the one for **Clean-Up Duty Hat**.

### Final answer:

Re-tag around 20 questions to earn Clean-Up Duty hat.

Finally after WB, we know it:

Edit 5 questions that later get upvoted.

Comment: That's how you get Peacekeeper hat, no?, i did that, only got Peacekeeper hat, not Clean-Up Duty hat...

Comment: Does the clean-up duty badge only apply to flagging, or does it also apply to close votes for 3k+ users?

Comment: Not sure about it, but it worked out in my case, also as I mentioned in my answer it was my recent activity nothing else than that.

Comment: It can't have anything to do with flagging, I didn't flag any posts on the site where I got it, all I had done were edits (adding tags to posts)

Comment: @U9-Forward don't know exact number, I made around 20-30 tag edits overall in recent day.

Comment: @NikhilKinkar Works, genius man, thanks so much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is incorrect. I retagged over 20 on SO and did not get it. I then performed a different action and got it. My belief is that it is related to retagging, but not just that.

Comment: It's so secret that you might get a visit by the secret-hats-squadron if you dare to tell others ;)